# How to store a range of column values in a 2-D array

Tags: arrays, excel

I used the below code to do the aove task:

```
Dim Arr(2,150)

Arr(0)=objsheet.Range("B16:B225").Value
```

But i am getting the error: "Subscript out of Range Error". Firstly is this the way to copy the cells ito array without usin any loops or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't.

You need:

```
Dim arr as Variant

arr = yourSheet.Range("B16:B225").value
```

Comment: It is working only if i remove as Variant. I am using Quick Test Professional. Why is this showin error if i am inclding variant

Comment: I don't know what Qucik Test Professional is. At a guess it isn't using VBA, it's using vbscript in which you don't declare types. Since you'd included the VBA and Excel tag - I'd assumed that your question related to Excel VBA.